# Disabling button on a particular row in WPF gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

This is my code for generating the gridview

```
        User u1 = new User();
        User u2 = new User();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            u1.Files = files[i];
            items.Add(u1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sharedFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            u2.Files += sharedFiles[i];
            items.Add(u2);
        }
        gridview1.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Files { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my xaml page

```
 <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Files}" ></GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Download" Click="fileDownloadClick" CommandParameter="{Binding Files}"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Share"  Click="fileShareClick"  CommandParameter="{Binding Files}" ></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView.Columns>

            </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
```

I would like to know if its possible to only allow my Share buttons disabled in my 2nd for loop (u2) while my Share buttons in (u1) is still enabled. Currently both are enabled. I am currently using  this to retrieve values for particular role

```
 private void fileShareClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object share = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter;
    }
```

Comment: If i understand you correct `CanExceute` could be a solution.

Comment: @Locas he is not using MVVM here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a DataTrigger on the Button which you want. and bind that with property that represent the boolen type value. like IsShareAllowed.

Try some thing like this.

```
var procs = (from p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()

                     select new
                     {
                         Name = p.ProcessName,

                         IsShareAllowed = Convert.ToBoolean(r.Next(-1, 1))
                     }).ToList(); ;

        list.ItemsSource = procs;
```

Xaml

```
 <ListView Name="list" Grid.Row="4">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridView.Columns>

                        <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />

                        <GridViewColumn >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="Download" Click="fileDownloadClick" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="Share"  Click="fileShareClick"  >
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShareAllowed}" Value="false">
                                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>                                        
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                    </GridView.Columns>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Jodha is it possible if u edit the code according to the one i posted. I tried applying what u said but im having some errors. I still need to use the CommandParameter="{Binding Files}" as  im binding the share buttons to my Files @Jodha

Comment: Thanks!! it works. However is it possible to not change the style of my button since im alrdy using a theme

Comment: This style will not change your Style of button it just uses the added values only.